# Action Bar Tabs CustomView too long

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

After finally getting each CustomView to wrap the Tab parent completely, I ran into a problem where the Tabs are too long and are turning the Action Bar into a slider. My drawables have widths of 150px , which should be fine because I tested the width in px of the Samsung Galaxy S2 screen and got 480px (480/3 tabs = 160px each).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Set-up:** Each Tab is set by the same RelativeLayout that has different drawawble resources attached to the layout. That layout is then passed to setCustomView() of the Tab. I don't think there is a need for an ImageView for each Tab, unless that would fix my problem. Some Style config changes such as removing left and right padding of the TabView have been made in order to place the custom views over the Tab.

**Code** (not using ImageView, setting drawable resource on RelativeLayout)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >

<!--     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivCustomTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tabsDescription"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
//setting up tabs + custom views on tabs
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout discoverTabLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_tabs, null);
    RelativeLayout tagsTabLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_tabs, null);
    RelativeLayout badgeTabLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_tabs, null);
    //ImageView customTabImg = (ImageView) customTabLayout.findViewById(R.id.ivCustomTab);  //re-setting this ImageView for each tab

    ActionBar.Tab discoverTab = actionBar.newTab();//.setText("Discover").setIcon(R.drawable.selector_tabicon_discover);//.setCustomView(drawable.selector_tab_discover);
    //customTabImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.selector_tab_discover);
    discoverTabLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_tab_discover);
    discoverTab.setCustomView(discoverTabLayout);
```

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.TabsNoPadding</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.TabsNoPadding</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.TabsNoPadding" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**What I've tried:**

- Adding android:layout_width="120dp" to RelativeLayout to shorten the Tabs, but the width stayed the same.
- Re-sized the images and reduced a total length of 45px, no change. And if I set them too small they won't cover the tab host.
- I've also noticed that the tabs customView(s) disappear onCreate() most of the time. Not sure if that has anything to do with the rendering off the tab scroll layout that I don't want.

I can post my Main Activity code if needed.

Comment: @Pratik Posted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest to think in dp(Density-independent pixel) instead of px(pixels) when working in Android.
2. If you want a custom tabbar I would suggest to simply create a LinearLayout with a width being set to match_parent and a height by your choice (for ex. 48dp). The orientation would be set to horizontal.

Inside the LinearLayout create as many ImageView or View as many tab you want and set the width to 0dp, height to match_parent and most importantly **weight** to 1 (without dp or any other unit) for each View inside the LinearLayout. This way the tabs will have the same width and they will remain inside the boundaries of the screen.

Hope this helps.